# How to extract href inside h5 tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to understand how to extract a h5 tag href from code that contains other h tags using beautiful soup?
For the below example I need to extract: 'https://www.podkasty.info/katalog/podkast/8730-Podcast_Tomasza_Terlikowskiego_Tak_my%C5%9Bl%C4%99' inside :

```
<article class="newest-episode">
                        <div class="newest-episode-body">
                            <img src="https://d3t3ozftmdmh3i.cloudfront.net/production/podcast_uploaded_episode400/5444321/5444321-1642001411295-4fd72d6f7def9.jpg" style="width: 100%; " loading="lazy" >
                            <h4 class="text-center">
                                                                    <a href="https://www.podkasty.info/katalog/podkast/5358-Podcasty_Oryginalne_EMPIK_GO/Rozwa%C5%BCna_i_erotyczna_Odcinek_specjalny_Czyje_jest">
                                    <strong>Rozważna i erotyczna | Odcinek specjalny: Czyje jest kobiece ciało? | Magda Mołek i Joanna Keszka</strong>
                                    <br />
                                    Podcasty Oryginalne EMPIK GO                                    </a><br />

                                <small>2022-02-10 07:00:00</small>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                                        </div>

            
            <h3>Podkasty ostatnio dodane do katalogu</h3>

                                                                                <article class="blog-post" >
                        <div class="blog-body">
                            <h5 class="text-center">
                                <a href="https://www.podkasty.info/katalog/podkast/8730-Podcast_Tomasza_Terlikowskiego_Tak_my%C5%9Bl%C4%99" >
                                    Podcast Tomasza Terlikowskiego | Tak myślę                                    </a>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </article>
```

I tried with:

```
res = requests.get(webpage) 
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='html.parser')
urls = soup.select('h5')

for url in urls:
    url_href = url.get('href')
```

but I result with url_href 'None'.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us what you've tried as a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what is `url` :

```py
import bs4

res_text = """
<article class="newest-episode">
   <div class="newest-episode-body">
      <img src="https://d3t3ozftmdmh3i.cloudfront.net/production/podcast_uploaded_episode400/5444321/5444321-1642001411295-4fd72d6f7def9.jpg" style="width: 100%; " loading="lazy" >
      <h4 class="text-center">
         <a href="https://www.podkasty.info/katalog/podkast/5358-Podcasty_Oryginalne_EMPIK_GO/Rozwa%C5%BCna_i_erotyczna_Odcinek_specjalny_Czyje_jest">
         <strong>Rozważna i erotyczna | Odcinek specjalny: Czyje jest kobiece ciało? | Magda Mołek i Joanna Keszka</strong>
         <br />
         Podcasty Oryginalne EMPIK GO                                    </a><br />
         <small>2022-02-10 07:00:00</small>
      </h4>
   </div>
</article>
</div>
<h3>Podkasty ostatnio dodane do katalogu</h3>
<article class="blog-post" >
   <div class="blog-body">
      <h5 class="text-center">
         <a href="https://www.podkasty.info/katalog/podkast/8730-Podcast_Tomasza_Terlikowskiego_Tak_my%C5%9Bl%C4%99" >
         Podcast Tomasza Terlikowskiego | Tak myślę                                    </a>
      </h5>
   </div>
</article>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res_text, features='html.parser')
urls = soup.select('h5')

for url in urls:
    print(url)
```

gives :

```html
<h5 class="text-center">
<a href="https://www.podkasty.info/katalog/podkast/8730-Podcast_Tomasza_Terlikowskiego_Tak_my%C5%9Bl%C4%99">
         Podcast Tomasza Terlikowskiego | Tak myślę                                    </a>
</h5>
```

So the name is wrong, it is the whole `h5` node and its content. Indeed, that's what you `select`ed : `soup.select('h5')`.
You should rename your variable, and change your selection :

```py
nodes = soup.select('h5>a[href]')  # the <a> nodes, direct children of <h5> nodes, and having an `href` attribute

for node in nodes:
    print(node["href"])
```

```
https://www.podkasty.info/katalog/podkast/8730-Podcast_Tomasza_Terlikowskiego_Tak_my%C5%9Bl%C4%99
```